# Saving image file using Fileupoad Control and sqldatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

I want to add a image file to my database using sqldatasource .

steps that i have taken

**1.Coverting image to Byte[] array.**

```
Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream; 
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs); 
Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
```

**2.Setting the update parameter type as Object**

```
<UpdateParameters>       
<asp:Parameter Name="File" Type="Object" /> 
</UpdateParameters>
```

**3.Adding byte array as update parameter in SqlDataSource control.**

```
sqlDataSource.UpdateParameters["File"].DefaultValue = bytes;
```

but when i compile this code it is giving me a error "is giving me a error

"Cannot Implicitly convert byte[] to string" at third step

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set parameter in [Updating event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updating.aspx)

```
private void sqlDataSource_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["File"].Value = bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make data type varbinary

and made datatype varbinary(max) in your database

Comment: you can only enter string type value to the DefaultValue .