# Problem with sqldatasource when passing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Part of the sqldatasource parameters:

```
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="AllQuestionAskedDataSource" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CP_AllQuestionsAnswered %>" SelectCommand="SELECT ThreadTitle
FROM Threads
WHERE UsersID=@UserID">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The code behind:

```
 Guid userid = UsefulStaticMethods.GetUserNameFromUserGuid(name);
 AllQuestionAskedDataSource.SelectParameters["UserID"].DefaultValue = userid;
```

It tells me that it cant convert userid from Guid to string. But the parameter must be a Guid for the select statement of the sqldatasource to work

Comment: Look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580061/saving-image-file-using-fileupoad-control-and-sqldatasource/6580383#6580383). Maybe it helps

Comment: What do your parameters in the `<asp:SqlDataSource>` look like??

Comment: see above..it is writen @UserID

Comment: Yeah I see that - but inside your `<asp:SqlDataSource>` you should have more content - a `<SelectParameters>` section etc. - that's where it would be defined what **data type** a parameter is.... most likely, this is set to "string" while you want to pass a "guid"

Comment: Reniuz, it doesnt help. marc..see update above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Guid"  />
     </SelectParameters>
```

**Updated Code**

```
<asp:Parameter Name="UserID" Type="Object" />
<asp:Parameter Name="MemberID" DbType="Guid" />
```

Comment: Error 3 Cannot create an object of type 'System.TypeCode' from its string representation 'Guid' for the 'Type' property. D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\Statistics.aspx 19

Comment: Type doesnt have such a property such as a Guid

Comment: Can you specify the type with the corresponding namespace?

Comment: Error 3 Cannot create an object of type 'System.TypeCode' from its string representation 'Guid' for the 'Type' property. D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\Statistics.aspx 19

Comment: No!! I cant it wont let me write ..Type="System.Guid"

Comment: this link may help you  http://forums.asp.net/t/1693801.aspx/1?Need+help+with+Insert+command+on+SqlDataSource+GUID+issue

Comment: Thats what i did right now, i used the sqldatasource selecting event, cause it has Evenargs parameter command

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write your custom parameter:

```
public class UserIdParameter : Parameter
{
    protected override object Evaluate(HttpContext context, 
        System.Web.UI.Control control)
    {
        var name = GetName();
        return UsefulStaticMethods.GetUserNameFromUserGuid(name);

    }
}

<SelectParameters>
        <custom:UserIdParameter Name="UserID" />
</SelectParameters>
```